# How to fix Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't find the error

```
<span onclick="(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
$(document).ready(function () {
$.imageMapProGoToFloor('floor 15', 'floor 15');
});
})(jQuery, window, document);" style="background-color: #2386D1; cursor:pointer; color: #fff; display: inline-block; padding: 3px 25px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 5px;">choose floor</span>
```

Comment: We can't either. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: jQuery is not defined, and why are you calling that function like that?

Comment: The javascript string in the html can't have unescaped line breaks. Using onclick like this is an outdated and poor practice

Comment: You are just dumping a complete jQUery script into an onclick without thought. The script does not belong in the onclick

Answer (score 0):

You are just dumping a complete jQuery script into an onclick without thought. This script does not belong in the onclick.

Additionally `$(document).ready(function () {` is executed on page load

It can be shortened to `$(function () {`

Perhaps you meant this

```js
$(function() {
  $(".goto").on("click", function() {
    const floorString = $(this).data("floor");
    $.imageMapProGoToFloor("Floors", floorString);
  })
})
```

using

```html
<span class="goto" data-floor="floor 15" style="background-color: #2386D1; cursor:pointer; color: #fff; display: inline-block; padding: 3px 25px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 5px;">choose floor 15 </span>
```